# How to prevent other iOS applications from printing to an AirPrint device?

Tags: ios, airprint

Is there any way to protect a printer such that it can only be used by a single application?

I would like to have a printer in a public network that will only accept print requests from my custom iOS application using the AirPrint feature of iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the iOS application sandbox as of iOS 5.0

Comment: That is what I figured, but you can always hope!